# How to loop through a list of pairs in scheme racket

Tags: scheme, racket

So I have this of pairs and I would like to iterate through all pairs and take its numeral and symbol for comparison. I need to check if the numeral is between  (1-7) or it is a J Q K. The symbol Needs to be always  H S D C, so I need to check that.
I know how to do the checks with the cons staments but I cannot find a way of iterating through all of the pairs and extract the first and second value.

```
(define n '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 "J" "Q" "K"))
(define s '( #\H #\S #\C #\D))
(define (deck)
  (apply append
       (map (lambda (x)
              (map (lambda (y) (cons x y))
                   s))
            n))
  )
(deck)


#((1 . #\H)
 (1 . #\S)
 (1 . #\C)
 (1 . #\D)
 (2 . #\H)
 (2 . #\S)
 (2 . #\C)
 (2 . #\D)
 (3 . #\H)
 (3 . #\S)
 (3 . #\C)
 (3 . #\D)
 (4 . #\H)
 (4 . #\S)
 (4 . #\C)
 (4 . #\D)
 (5 . #\H)
 (5 . #\S)
 (5 . #\C)
 (5 . #\D)
 (6 . #\H)
 (6 . #\S)
 (6 . #\C)
 (6 . #\D)
 (7 . #\H)
 (7 . #\S)
 (7 . #\C)
 (7 . #\D)
 ("J" . #\H)
 ("J" . #\S)
 ("J" . #\C)
 ("J" . #\D)
 ("Q" . #\H)
 ("Q" . #\S)
 ("Q" . #\C)
 ("Q" . #\D)
 ("K" . #\H)
 ("K" . #\S)
 ("K" . #\C)
 ("K" . #\D))
#
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What checks are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't iterate or loop, you either recurse or use higher-order functions like `map`.

Comment: sounds fair. Please could you show a template of a higher order function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most promising solution is to [`(filter)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) the list by applying [`(member)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29) to the `(cdr)` of each list element to test whether it is a member of the suits. You can do the same for the faces as well, if need be, and it is trivial to do both in a single pass. This should work:

```
(define faces '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 "J" "Q" "K"))
(define suits '( #\H #\S #\C #\D))

(define (deck)
  (apply append
       (map (lambda (x)
              (map (lambda (y) (cons x y))
                   suits))
            faces)))

(define original-deck (deck))

(define (sanitize-deck d)
  (filter (lambda (ls)
            (and (member (car ls) faces)
                 (member (cdr ls) suits)))
          d))
```

Where the output of `sanitize-deck` is the final desired output.

Comment: i want the funtion to return #t if all cards are valid and false if they are not.

Comment: @brovia that needs to be in the question as it alters the answer. You also need to show what effort you have made ie what have tried and what don't you understand.

Comment: you re completely right. I solved this later same day, just was looking for some template.